# how to find the package related to a function

Tags: r

In ChainLadder package, when I try to run line by line of language -> BootChainLadder, there are some functions used such as getDiagonal, checkTriangle, getIndivDFs etc,  which throws an error as couldnot find function "XXXX"

For example: when using getDiagonal error is

Error in getDiagonal(xxxx) : 
  could not find function "getDiagonal"

I am not sure are these functions are used from different packages.
Can someone help me how to fix this?

Comment: If you're using RStudio, you can try typing something like `??"getDiagonal"` in the console.

Answer (score 2):

I find that the `findFn` in the `sos` package is the widest search option for CRAN hosted packages. If you use `??` you will only be able to find the functions that are exposed by packages you have already installed. In your case, I wonder if there was a blog you were copying code, from since that function seems to be outside the horizon of CRAN:

```
install.packages("sos")
trying URL 'http://cloud.r-project.org/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.5/sos_2.0-0.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 276618 bytes (270 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 270 KB


The downloaded binary packages are in
    /var/folders/yq/m3j1jqtj6hq6s5mq_v0jn3s80000gn/T//RtmpE3WlUA/downloaded_packages
library(sos)

findFn("getDiagonal")
#--------
found 0 matches
x has zero rows;   nothing to display.
```

So then you widen the search even further with a google search on "chainladder getdiagonal" and find that it inside the code for `BootChainLadder` in a GitHub site: https://github.com/mages/ChainLadder/blob/master/R/BootstrapReserve.R

So it's perhaps going to appear in a subsequent version of ChainLadder and you have not installed the development version of ChainLadder. Actually trying that fails to get it in a form that can be loaded. The only place I've been able to find it is on that gitHub page as an internally defined function inside BootChainLadder. However, it's not in the `ChainLadder:: BootChainLadder` function in the development or stable versions of the package. So I guess you are on the "bleeding edge".

Comment: As you mentioned installed sos library and used findFn. Getting below error: findFn("getIndivDFs")
Error in findFn("getIndivDFs") : could not find function "findFn". If I try to attach the package sos, getting info message as                                                                                                                 Attaching package: ‘sos’

The following object is masked from ‘package:utils’:

    ?                                                                                                                          Any help on this?

Comment: The functions used in the package are inside the package. R couldn't recognise the function written inside the code! Can someone tell me how can R use the function inside the code?